# Can someone break into a Leomund's Tiny Hut via the Ethereal Plane?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wizard, ethereal-plane

I've got players who rely heavily on Leomund's Tiny hut for a "safe" night time rest.  I'm alright with them using it to help, but it gets irritating having a wrench thrown into my nighttime attacks.  I have found some ways to deal such as Dispel Magic or having something camp them.  One time, I even attacked and killed their horses which were outside the hut. I was going to try a burrowing creature but [SageAdvice put forward that there IS a floor in the hut](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/73879/can-one-enter-leomunds-tiny-hut-from-below?rq=1).  That's when I came across the Phase Spider.  So the question:

Could something move into the Ethereal Plane, get to an area that would be inside Leomund's Tiny Hut, and then move back to the Material Plane?

Comment: If you're looking for ways to mess with your party's use of Tiny Hut, this question has a number of ideas and suggestions: [Realistically, does Leomund’s Tiny Hut allow for indefinite long rests in a dungeon?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/137458/39969)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

### No, Leomund's Tiny Hut is made of magical force which blocks passage in the Ethereal Plane

In the description of the [Border Ethereal](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/creating-a-multiverse#BorderEthereal) on DMG p. 48:

> A traveler on the Ethereal Plane is invisible and utterly silent to someone on the overlapped plane, and solid objects on the overlapped plane don’t hamper the movement of a creature in the Border Ethereal. **The exceptions are certain magical effects (including anything made of magical force)** and living beings.

So, objects made of magical force will block passage on the Ethereal Plane just as they do on the Material plane.

The description for [Leomund's Tiny Hut](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/tiny-hut) (PHB, p. 255) says:

> A 10-foot radius immobile **dome of force** springs into existence around and above you and remains stationary for the duration.

So, since Leomund's Tiny Hut is a dome of magical force, it should protect your party from intruders on the Ethereal Plane as well.

Comment: I had a feeling that I missed something.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction in the DMG!

Comment: @ConfusedDM: You did. Teleport will get through.

Comment: @Joshua IF you don't have to see where you are teleporting to. You can't see into the dome.

Comment: Dimension Door (4th level conjuration) should be able to pierce it.  You do NOT NEED to see your landing location if the outside is opaque.

Answer (score 3):

#### A lose reading of the DMG rules suggests that a *Tiny Hut* blocks the passage through the Ethereal Plane.

As divibisan's [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/150463/63061) states, the DMG rules about movement in the Bordered Ethereal strongly implies that going in and out a *Tiny Hut* via the Ethereal plane is not possible.

#### Actually, the above ruling is a DM call.

Anyway, this is one possible interpretation of the rules, since the spell description does not say anything about blocking the passage in the Ethereal plane, while there are spells that specify this:

- [*Wall of Force*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wall-of-force) (emphasis mine):

> Nothing can physically pass through the wall. It is immune to all damage and can't be dispelled by dispel magic. A disintegrate spell destroys the wall instantly, however. **The wall also extends into the Ethereal Plane, blocking ethereal travel through the wall.**

- [*Forcecage*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/forcecage)\$^1\$ (emphasis mine):

> A creature inside the cage can't leave it by nonmagical means. [...] **The cage also extends into the Ethereal Plane, blocking ethereal travel.**

---

\$^1\$ credits to [Soulstreak](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/64712/soulstreak) for having pointed this out in the comments.

Comment: It might be worth noting that Forcecage also blocks ethereal travel (which only supports the reading that tiny hut shouldnt block ethereal travel) https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/forcecage

Comment: @Soulstreak Good point: added to the answer!

Comment: @Eddymage Just a head up, the most effective way to credit someone is by linking to their profile since the name might change, and since the comment is now obsolete thanks to becoming part of the answer :)

Comment: -1: The absence of redundant information in this spell that is expressed (but still redundant) in other spells does not negate the rule from the DMG. Or to put it another way, you can't use the absence of information to negate a rule, exceptions to rules in 5e must be specific (and explicit) per the specific vs general rule.

Comment: @illustro If someone is playing with [basic rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-d-the-planes-of-existence#TransitivePlanes) then the case against Tiny Hut blocking ethereal plane is much weaker, though.

Comment: @WakiNadiVellir Someone playing with just the basic rules doesn't have access to the rule from the DMG, and the basic rules pdf on WoTCs website explicitly leaves out all of the Multiverse rules (so I'm not entirely clear if the basic ruleset on D&D Beyond is correct, in including the truncated information). It doesn't make it not exist. They are just playing the game without the full set of rules (in some ways they are playing a different game). The question, however, is asking about the full fledged ruleset, not the basic rules.