# Can a dragon's breath weapon pass through Leomund's Tiny Hut?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, dragons, breath-weapon

*Leomund's tiny hut* can protect against magic, objects, and creatures from entering.

A dragon's breath weapon is not considered magical, but has to be an object at least - which should be blocked by the hut.

[Sage Advice, however, rules that a dragon's breath can pass through the hut.](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2018/01/29/does-the-breath-weapon-go-through-leomunds-tiny-hut/) I typically rule with Sage Advice, but is this a situation where Crawford got it wrong?

Can a dragon's breath weapon pass through *Leomund's tiny hut*?

Comment: [JC's tweets are now officially unofficial](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8787/how-should-we-handle-answers-that-use-jeremy-crawfords-now-unofficial-tweets). They are considered to be advice, not errata on the rules.

Comment: Hi ConfusedDM! Welcome to rpg.se! Take the [tour], visit the [help] or ask here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if anything on the site confuses you. Thanks for contributing and happy gaming!

Comment: Related Question:  ["What Is Considered An Object?"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/95532/what-is-considered-an-object)  See especially [this answer.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/121385/18269)

Comment: Related : [Realistically, does Leomund’s Tiny Hut allow for indefinite long rests in a dungeon?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/137458/45757)

Answer (score 55):

## A dragon's breath shouldn't be able to pass through

I agree with other answers that RAW a dragon's breath can pass through the Hut.

However, I believe that in this case, sticking to a RAW ruling can hurt your game.

### Consistency

In any other situation, the Hut prevents just about anything, any attack from passing through. The dragon breath is an edge case that diverts from the simple rule and will damage immersion for your players (source : when I told my players about this ruling, the answers I got were "Wait what?", "That makes no sense" etc. and we collectively decided to ignore it)

### RAI

The Hut aims to provide a safe space to rest, where the players can't be attacked from the outside. This ruling makes no sense in that context, and is (in my opinion) just the result of a poorly-worded spell.

Comment: "the Hut prevents just about anything". I don't think that is correct, any non magical fire could pass through, as well as any non magical airborne poisons or acids, any smells (stench abilities ghast, stench cow), any non magical noises (banshees wail?), non magical light attacks (have no example). A lot can get through the hut RAW

Comment: That's not really pertinent, since this is an answer about using your GM knowledge to overrule the RAW when it is unclear or bad. In my game those effects you list would not reach through the Hut anyway.

Comment: That is of course your right to rule in your game. However I find the answer misleading because you argue that the hut should prevent these effects because "the Hut prevents just about anything". But that is not true unless you rule it like this. Its a recursive argument and I do find that relevant to note.

Comment: @findusl The way I see it the spell is presented as "a safe space". That's the simple rule. Now you could make a separate case for each of the things you list that they should pass the barrier, based on some reason or another. Your GM might let some pass, and reject others, based on different reasons ("comfortable atmosphere clause", is/isn't an object) and each of those rulings might be reasonable in itself. However by doing this you're over-interpreting the rule and creating a kludge of special cases

Comment: Whereas I argue that you would have a better and smoother game by having a simple rule "harmful things stay out" which is easy to interpret and doesn't require everyone to remember 10 different rulings

Comment: Also you list, like, 5 things. That's still not a lot that can get through. I still believe we're in the domain of edge cases.

Comment: You might consider them edge cases, but enemies who will want to kill the party and see their tiny hut will try and find a way through it. Also any environmental hazards, like heat or cold, strong winds, high water, swamp gases. Would you allow a caster to survive the plane of fire assuming they survive the one minute casting time?  It seems very powerful for a 3rd level ritual spell. Also btw anyone could teleport into a tiny hut, because that would not be passing through the barrier. I never considered that as not clear, but by your description you would forbid that as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115258/discussion-between-pierre-cathe-and-findusl).

Answer (score 28):

Here is the relevant text from *tiny hut*

> All other creatures and objects are barred from passing through it. Spells and other magical effects can’t extend through the dome or be cast through it.

Since

- [dragon breath is not magical](https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/rules-answers-february-2016) (not a magic item, a spell, spell attack, and no mention of being magical in its description),
- [not an object](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/121385/40999) (it is not discrete and not inanimate, as [Crawford's definition of object](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/823995293792243712)),
- obviously not a creature, and
- not a spell,

it can extend through the dome, and of course deals damage to anyone caught within its area.

This is supported by [Jeremy Crawford's tweet](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2018/01/29/does-the-breath-weapon-go-through-leomunds-tiny-hut/).

> > The breath weapon of a dragon is not a spell or magical effect and presumably wouldn't be considered an object so would go through Leomund's Tiny Hut like it wasn't there, yes?
>
> That's correct.

While the ruling is considered unofficial, since it is not on the [Sage Advice Compendium](https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/sage-advice/sage-advice-compendium) yet, his ruling is considered significant since he is the rules designer of DnD 5e. His ruling usually is a good barometer on how the intent of published rules should work.

RAW, the dragon breath is **not blocked** by *tiny hut*, but the DM is always free to rule otherwise, possibly by ruling that a fire breath or cold breath is negated by this clause:

> The atmosphere inside the space is comfortable and dry, regardless of the weather outside.

Comment: I wouldn't classify fire/cold breath as "weather" though

Comment: The part about the weather is neither defining nor limiting.  The atmosphere inside is comfortable and dry.  In fact, it doesn't actually mention temperature it just says "comfortable."  Noxious fumes and poison gas are not comfortable, right?

Comment: @krb Enter Leomund's Tiny Hut, where even your uncomfortable emotions will abate! Argument with the parents? Leomund's Tiny Hut! Let that uncomfortable social atmosphere magically disperse!

Comment: would non-magical fire be able to penetrate the Hut ?

Comment: @Manuki RAW, yes.

Answer (score 18):

Leomund's Tiny Hut blocks three classes of things:  Creatures, Spells/Magical Effects, and Objects.  Let's treat these in turn:

1. Dragon Breath is not a creature.  This is not in dispute.
2. Dragon Breath is not a Spell or Magical effect, on the basis of this [Sage Advice](https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/rules-answers-february-2016) which is a bit long and florally worded to reproduce, but draws a distinction between the pervasive, ambient magic of the D&D world vs the concentrated magic of a Spell or Magical Effect.  Dragon Breath is placed definitively in the first category and beyond the reach of *Anti-Magic Shield*, and presumably also *Leomund's Tiny Hut*.
3. Dragon Breath is not an object.  The DMG on page 246, as referenced by [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/121385/18269) and [this Crawford tweet](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/823995293792243712), defines an object as:

> For the purpose of these rules, an object is a discrete, inanimate
>   item like a window, door, sword, book, table, chair, or stone, not a
>   building or a vehicle that is composed of many other objects.

And [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/134824/18269) draws on that definition to opine (and I agree) that gasses and liquids don't qualify as objects because they are not discrete items.  On that basis, it is hard to see how any of the traditional Dragon Breaths listed in the 5e MM (acid, fire, poison gas, lightning, sleep gas, repulsion energy, slowing gas, weakening gas, paralyzing gas, icy cold) could be considered as discrete objects.

Since it fails all three tests, it is not blocked.

Comment: Your first sentence is incorrect.  "The atmosphere inside the space is comfortable and dry, regardless of the weather outside."   Therefore the hut is clearly able to block heat, cold and all forms of water (rain, snow, sleet, etc.) in addition to the 3 things you list.

Answer (score 9):

As I mentioned in the comments, JC's tweets on twitter are considered as advice, not official rulings. However, as per the [Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf):

> Official rulings on how to interpret rules are made here in the Sage Advice Compendium by the game’s lead rules designer, Jeremy Crawford (@JeremyECrawford on Twitter).

So the process is that people ask JC for advice on Twitter. The development team then publish any of these posts that they consider to be fair and accurate interpretations of the rules into the Sage Advice Compendium.

One clarification they have made is that Dragon's breath in *not* magical, by the definition of what interacts with Leomund's Tiny Hut:

> **Is the breath weapon of a dragon magical?**
>
> If you cast *antimagic field*, don *armor of invulnerability*, or use another feature of the game that protects against magical or nonmagical effects, you might ask yourself, “Will this protect me against a dragon’s breath?” **The breath weapon of a typical dragon isn’t considered magical, so *antimagic field* won’t help you but *armor of invulnerability* will.**

So, following that ruling, JC's tweet is correct; Dragon's breath is *not* magical, by the definition of the requirements of the Leomund's Tiny Hut spell; the breath won't be blocked by the hut.

Comment: It may (or may not) to assert that dragons are *special*. It's unsupportable beyond this 'loophole', but a DM could just say that Dragons figured out a way around this annoying cover over their food.

Comment: @NautArch: Interesting point, but for consistency that would also have to apply to Dragonborn humanoids, too, including PCs being able to breathe *out* of a dome.  Although without that flavour limitation to only dragon-derived breath weapons, the reasoning in this answer arguably also applies to non-magical poison gas, if green dragon breath can get in/out.  (e.g. set off a trapped chest you happen to have with you, and smoke em out of their hut.)  At some point the comfortable atmosphere clause should deal with gas, though.

Answer (score 3):

### No, a dragon's breath cannot, in general, pass through Leomund's Tiny Hut

The key line of the spell that prevents it is ***emphasised*** in this quote:

> Creatures and objects within the dome when you cast this spell can move through it freely. All other creatures and objects are barred from passing through it. Spells and other magical effects can't extend through the dome or be cast through it. ***The atmosphere inside the space is comfortable and dry, regardless of the weather outside.***

It is important to point out that the modifier added to the end of the last sentence in that quote:

> [...] regardless of the weather outside.

Means the last sentence applies to "weather" from outside the hut affecting the "atmosphere" inside the hut. Notably, it means the sentence does not cover things originating *inside* the hut from changing the "atmosphere" inside the hut. All effects should be viewed with this lens applied. For our purposes, the dragon's breath weapons definitively originate *outside* of the hut, and are thus caught by this sentence.

#### Restrictions on dragon's breath weapons entering the hut as a result of this last sentence

First things first, ["weather"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/weather) is defined as:

> the state of the atmosphere with respect to heat or cold, wetness or dryness, calm or storm, clearness or cloudiness

or

> disagreeable atmospheric conditions: such as
>
> - RAIN, STORM
> - cold air with dampness

Next ["atmosphere"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/atmosphere) which is defined as:

> the air of a locality

or

> the gaseous envelope of a celestial body (such as a planet)

So, in particular the gases inside the hut will always be comfortable and dry. The types of dragons breath we have currently in the game can be summarised as follows:

- Some form of gas (Green, Brass, Faerie, etc)
- Acid (Black)
- Fire (Red, Gold)
- Lightning (Blue, Bronze)
- Icy Blast (White, Silver)

The gas forms of breath are immediately excluded, as they would make the atmosphere in the hut decidedly uncomfortable (unless the caster is immune to the specific gas).

Acid is also excluded as, by definition, [acid](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/acid) is:

> a sour substance
>
> *specifically* : any of various typically water-soluble and sour compounds that in solution are capable of reacting with a base (see BASE entry 1 sense 6a) to form a salt, redden litmus, and have a pH less than 7, that are hydrogen-containing molecules or ions able to give up a proton to a base, or that are substances able to accept an unshared pair of electrons from a base

This is excluded explicitly by virtue of the requirement to that the interior of the be ***dry*** regardless of what is happening outside. So the hut is clearly capable of blocking liquids, and getting doused by a liquid is the very definition of being [wet](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wet):

> consisting of, containing, covered with, or soaked with liquid (such as water)

The Icy Blast is also excluded, as it causes cold damage by drastically lowering the temperature. We can see this from the description of the White Dragon:

> [...] Larger treasures and chests are encased in layers of rime created by the white dragon's breath, and held safe between layers of transparent ice.

I don't know about you, but temperatures cold enough to cause accumulations of a crust of ice on objects would be a decidedly uncomfortable environment to be in (unless you are immune to the cold). They are also firmly in the definition of "weather" presented above.

That leaves us with Fire and Lightning breath. We know the dragon's breath weapon is not magical (as confirmed by an official Sage Advice ruling), as a result the Fire and Lightning produced respectively is not magical Fire or Lightning. This means it needs to conform to the regular rules for such occurrences.

So we need to ask:

#### What *is* fire and what *is* lightning?

[**Fire**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fire) is defined as:

> fuel in a state of combustion (as on a hearth)

For fire to exist, three things are required, Oxygen, fuel and heat. We clearly have heat and Oxygen, so that leaves the fuel. Thus, in order to exist as fire in the hut the fuel the dragon's breath is burning must travel with it into the hut. The fuel itself is certainly an object (or at least each element of fuel is an object) and as a result cannot pass into the hut. All that remains is the heat. Again, I don't know about you, but being in a hut with air hot enough to cause significant damage is not *my* idea of a comfortable atmosphere! Additionally, "heat" falls under the definition of "weather" outside. Thus the fire breath is blocked by the hut.

[**Lightning**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lightning) is defined as:

> the flashing of light produced by a discharge of atmospheric electricity

Here the definition contains the key word, ***atmosphere***! An electrified atmosphere is not a comfortable one for most forms of life! Thus we must conclude that the hut also blocks lightning breath.

---

Side Notes:

- [Tweets from Jeremy Crawford are not official rulings](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/140221/with-the-2019-sage-advice-compendium-release-are-jeremy-crawfords-tweets-consi) (this has been clarified in the [2019 PDF release of the official Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf) from WoTC)
- The phrase "Sage Advice" is included in both the name of an unofficial site dedicated to collating Jeremy Crawford's tweets, and the name Wizards of the Coast gives to their official rulings document. The document you have linked to is from the former, and is such is not an official ruling.

Comment: "The atmosphere inside the space is comfortable and dry, regardless of the weather outside." is DESCRIPTIVE, not PRESCRIPTIVE. It's flavor, not ruling.  A wizard inside can cast *ice storm* INSIDE.  You can't say "ah ah ah, it's not comfortable or dry, so no he can't".

Comment: @jnovack in 5e spells don't have flavour text

Comment: Mass Heal: "A **flood of healing energy** flows from you..."
Heroes Feast: "You bring forth a **great feast**, including **magnificent food and drink**"
Hungar of Hadar: "The void is filled with a **cacophony of soft whisters and slurping noises**... The void creates a **warp in fabric of space**."
Fireball: "..and then **blossoms with a low roar**"

Those are three examples I found in minutes, none of those descriptions have any bearing on rules, they are all flavor.

Comment: @jnovack https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/78012/36850

Comment: If you want to argue about that point, that question is the place to do it.

Comment: Other answers cite sources that loose liquid or similar is not "an object".  I think we can exclude acid breath on the basis of "... and dry", though, without needing to make that argument.  (At least if we use the comfortable part to exclude poison gas, and fire / lightning / cold).

Comment: This reasoning prevents cooking food inside the hut, since any source of heat hot enough to cook would be decidedly uncomfortable. Also, this reasoning would prevent getting washed, or even drinking, inside the hut, because water is wet.

Comment: @WakiNadiVellir no it doesn't. Building a fire inside the tiny hut doesn't come from *outside* the tiny hut. Same goes for drinking, getting washed etc. The rule has the qualifier that it's comfortable and dry regardless of what is happening outside (speaking colloquially), not stuff that you do inside.

Comment: @illustro I was referring to your arguments based on *"The atmosphere inside the space is comfortable and dry, regardless of the weather outside."*. It's not about what can pass through, it's what it's like inside, that sentence doesn't block anything from passing through (also, breath weapon is not "weather").

Comment: @WakiNadiVellir because of the qualifier at the end of the sentence, the sentence is entirely about what is passing through and the effect it would have on the atmosphere inside (ie without the "regardless of the weather outside" it would be very specifically about the atmosphere in the hut). Also "weather" has a *very* loose definition in English: "the state of the atmosphere at a particular place and time as regards heat, cloudiness, dryness, sunshine, wind, rain, etc". So dragon's breath changes the "weather" of a place at a particular time by virtue of changing the atmosphere.

Comment: In the object section, do you think this refers to "stone" as a substance? Given the series of objects that come before it, I would think it talks about "a stone", like "a pebble" or "a rock". Apart from the substance issue, it is not entirely clear if body of liquid counts as an object or not - by the examples or definitions, rather not, but that would lead to non-inflammable oil spills ... it is at least ambiguous. Agree with Peter, you do not realyl need it here, you can just go by "dry". I think less is more here and leaving liquid objects out would make for a stronger case.

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin updated regarding that

Comment: @WakiNadiVellir clarified regarding the modifier clause of the sentence and the word weather.

Comment: @PeterCordes that is a much more succinct argument

Comment: Describing the effects of a dragon's breath weapon as "weather" is a maliciously contorted misreading of the definition of "weather". Dragon's breath isn't *weather*. The dome prevents the atmosphere from becoming uncomfortable as a result of weather, but you're stretching that clause to indicate that it remains comfortable regardless of *any* exterior conditions, when the clause seems to make it clearly limited to weather conditions.

Answer (score 0):

RAW, the breath attack shouldn’t penetrate.

I’d cite the clause of the spell which explicitly describes it as “a wall of force”, which stands to reason that it provides an equal and opposite reaction force to a body exerting force onto it. The hut can clearly repel water from its weather control clause, so it stands to reason that an acid breath attack would be repelled.

As for lightning breath weapons, if the hut can repel a lightning strike in a thunderstorm, then the breath attack shouldn’t pass through either.

As for fire breath attacks... I can see two different ways that plays out. Either the breath attack is like a flamethrower, which spews out napalm, hence acting as a more viscous fluid, or it’s more like an acetylene gas torch, where the fluid combusts completely, and “flame” part of the fire is just extremely hot gas particles being propelled by the pressure with which the gas was expelled. If it’s more like the first case, then the fluid would be repelled as if it were rain. If it’s superheated gas particles, the hut should block (most) of the particles from passing the boundary as it would block liquids. I’m treating a gas as just a not-very viscous Fluid over here.

As for the heat.... it’s most likely a constant pressure-type combustion because once the breath attack is released, the gas expands when combusted, hence volume increases. The heat energy is transferred via the work done by the gas particles on whatever object is being bombarded by them. If the gas particles are indeed blocked, then most of the heat should be mitigated between the force wall and temperature control from the spell effect.

No idea how repulsion breath would interact. It’s not strictly magical, and I can’t think of any physical explanation for it.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. A slight correction: *tiny hut* describes itself as a "dome of force" (not a "wall of force"). Also, for completeness, your answer doesn't mention the brass dragon's sleep breath, the copper's slowing breath, the gold's weakening breath, the green's poison breath, or the white dragon's cold breath weapons. (Or the faerie dragon's euphoria breath...)

Answer (score -3):

I know this is pretty old, but I would like to add that as per the Monster Manual

> Dragons are also magical creatures whose innate power fuels their
> dreaded breath weapons and other preternatural abilities. Pag. 86, MM

I would interpret it as this: dragons' "innate power" is granted by their status as magical creatures, the innate power fuels their breaths, thus their breaths are magical.

Thus, *tiny hut* protects against it.

Answer (score -7):

I'll go with a dictionary definition...

What is an "object"?
Well, according to Merriam Webster an object can be "something material that may be perceived by the senses" [(according to definition 1.a)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/object).

So how do we define "something material"? It's something "relating to, derived from, or consisting of matter" [(according to definition 1.a.1)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/material)...

So how do we really define "matter"? For this once, we have to read more than simply the first entry...

 Looking up ["matter" in a dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/matter), I find entry number 2 relates to the relevant use of the word "matter", as is clearly demonstrated by 2.a: "the substance of which a physical object is composed".

Reading on entry 2.b tells me everything I need to know... "material substance that occupies space, has mass, and is composed predominantly of atoms consisting of protons, neutrons, and electrons, that constitutes the observable universe, and that is interconvertible with energy".

Great! So the gasses which fire consists of IS technically matter, furthermore we now know that a fire is "material" and it can certainly be perceived by the senses...

So fire is, technically, an object. Therefore a dragon's breath can't pass through a Leomund's Tiny Hut by RAW, just like it can't rain into the hut and just like I can't shovel sand on the hut and have it pass through.

(Oxygen CAN however pass into the hut, since we can't perceive it with the senses, only the lack of it can be perceived, and then only from the effect not having oxygen has on our bodies, we're not actually perceiving the oxygen. Conversely the same is true of certain harmful gasses...)

Comment: Having to read through 3 separate dictionary definitions to rule an edge case is madness territory