# Would an anti-magic field block targets of Dragon's Breath spell user?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, antimagic-field

Consider someone has [*dragon's breath*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dragons-breath) cast on them.

> Until the spell ends, the creature can use an action to exhale energy of the chosen type in a 15-foot cone.

**What happens if this creature exhale energy on targets inside an antimagic field?**

Does the effect pass through as if it were [a dragon's breath weapon](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/157190/would-an-anti-magic-zone-affect-a-dragons-breath-weapon)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

An anti magic field does prevent the Dragon's Breath spell from affecting targets in an anti-magic field. In the spell's description, it says

> You touch one willing creature and imbue it with the power to spew **magical** energy from its mouth...

(Emphasis Mine)

This shows that this effect is intended to be magical, and therefore does not work in an antimagic field, where

> Spells and other magical effects, except those created by an artifact or a deity, are suppressed [inside] and can't protrude into it