# Can Arcane Abeyance allow you to cast a spell longer than one action in one action?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, wizard, spellcasting

I recently did this in a campaign of mine and it... ruffled the DM's feathers to say the least.

*Arcane Abeyance* is a 10th level Arcane Tradition for the *Chronurgy Wizard* that allows the caster to condense a 4th level spell or lower into a "mote":

> When you cast a spell using a spell slot of 4th level or lower, you can condense the spell's magic into a mote. **The spell is frozen in time at the moment of casting and held within a gray bead for 1 hour.** This bead is a Tiny object with AC 15 and 1 hit point, and it is immune to poison and psychic damage. When the duration ends, or if the bead is destroyed, it vanishes in a flash of light, and the spell is lost.
>
> **A creature holding the bead can use its action to release the spell within, whereupon the bead disappears.** The spell uses your spell attack bonus and save DC, and the spell treats the creature who released it as the caster for all other purposes.

Emphasis mine. As one might tell from my profile, I'm a huge fan of the wonderfully balanced *[Leomund's Tiny Hut](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/137458/realistically-does-leomund-s-tiny-hut-allow-for-indefinite-long-rests-in-a-dung)*. The following occurred last night in our campaign:

> Obnoxious, power-gaming Wizard and party come face to face with a horrible monster with many claws. With an initiative of 31 (because Chronurgy Wizard is wonderfully balanced), the Wizard releases his pre-prepared mote of *Leomund's Tiny Hut* and summons a hemispherical dome inside of the dungeon, blocking the exit with the party inside.
>
> Because *Leomund's Tiny Hut* allows for objects to pass out of the barrier but not in, the party peppered to death the poor monster without it having any ability to respond while the Wizard smoked his pipe wistfully. The monster, having no magical ability whatsoever, proceeds to waste its turns digging and attempting to dodge as the party massacres the creature in its own home.

My question is, was the above situation legal, RAW? Is this really allowed and can Arcane Abeyance allow for spells with long cast times to be shortened to a single Action?

Comment: To make the question *clearly* not a duplicate, removing the 2nd question (last sentence) should be enough.

Comment: Decided this wasnt a duplicate. I think its closely related, but I think its appropriate to have a specific question about how a feature works, even if that feature working is assumed as an answer to a different question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Yes, this works.

I actually came to this exact realization a few months ago. [In chat I wrote](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/11?m=55778549#55778549):

> Whoa, the Chronurgy Wizard can create a *quick release Tiny Hut*.

You have emphasized all of the correct rules concerning the Chronurgy Wizard's Arcane Abeyance feature. If you take the time to cast the spell, the spell is then condensed into the mote, *and can be released using only an action*:

> A creature holding the bead *can use its action* to release the spell within, whereupon the bead disappears.

The bead is frozen in time at the moment the spell's energy would be released, ready to be released by whoever holds the bead, only using their action to do so.

So yes, this does allow for quick release *tiny hut*, as well as my favorite instant spell, *Galder's Tower* (normally 10 minutes):

> You conjure a two-story tower made of stone, wood, or similar suitably sturdy materials.

Comment: note whatever objects those inside shoot out the enemy can shoot back in. I had players shoot a giant with a ballista from inside the hut, they were real surprised when the giant started jabbing into the hut with the ballista bolt like a it was a dagger.

Comment: The question seems to assume that Leomunds Tiny Hut is effectively a tank in this situation, but you might want to address how it works in the answer, for completeness, and for the sake of those wondering if you can attack from inside a tiny hut.

Comment: [Does a Leomund's Tiny Hut prevent physical melee attacks from outside vs targets inside?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/174871),

Comment: I would also argue as a DM that on the initial cast all conditions would have to be set. As an example: You have to designate those able to pass through the hut as you place the spell into the mote, not when the mote is activated. Meaning someone that accompanies or joins last minute would not be protected.