# Can arcane abeyance hold ritual spells?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature

If a level 10 chronomancy wizard ritual casts water breathing could they use arcane abeyance to put it in a bead for later?

Comment: You are dropping a lot of questions very quickly. You may want to slow down a bit as it looks like you're not even trying to figure these things out on your own first (aka no research effort.)

Comment: @NautArch ok! I had done some research on this but it was to settle an argument between me and a friend! I was told on another post to put individual questions in their own post and not group similar ones. the reason I am posting so many is that I had a bunch of questions saved up between me and others and i am just now having a chance to post! i am happy to let this be my last one for a bit! i was just trying to get some clarification

Comment: Related: "[Can Arcane Abeyance allow you to cast a spell longer than one action in one action?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/179491)"

Answer (score 15):

#### Arcane Abeyance only works with spells cast using spell slots, which ritual-cast spells are not

The Arcane Abeyance features states (emphasis mine):

> When you cast a spell **using a spell slot of 4th level or lower**, you can condense the spell's magic into a mote. [...]

However, the section on "[Rituals](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#Rituals)" states:

> [...] The ritual version of a spell takes 10 minutes longer to cast than normal. It also doesn't expend a spell slot, which means the ritual version of a spell can't be cast at a higher level. [...]

Because ritual-cast spells do *not* expend a spell slot, they cannot be used with Arcane Abeyance.